# How to calculate the value of one field by modifying the value of another and vice versa

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two fields

```html
<input v-model="amount_ttc" @change="setAmountHtva">
<input v-model="amount_htva" @change="setAmountTtc">
```

My datas :

```js
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      amount_ttc: 0,
      amount_htva: 0,
      vat: 21
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setAmountHtva () {
        this.amount_htva = parseFloat(this.amount_ttc / (1 + this.vat / 100)).toFixed(2)
    },
    setAmountTtc () {
        this.amount_ttc = parseFloat(this.amount_htva * (1 + this.vat / 100)).toFixed(2)
    }
  }
}
```

If I fill in the `amount_ttc` field, I would like the `amount_htva` field to be calculated automatically.
If I fill in the `amount_htva` field, I would like the `amount_ttc` field to be calculated automatically.

What I am doing is not working.

I get an error message informing me of an infinite loop.

I think it's because when I modify field A, I calculate field B (which changes, so I calculate field A again)

I don't know how to get what I want.

Comment: What if try to change an event form @change to @focus? While one input will be focused, another not, so it will not causing loop

Comment: It should be enough if you add `:value="amount_ttc"` and `:value="amount_htva"` to the corresponding inputs. That sets initial value for `v-model` without triggering `@change`. Once you actually change the value, `@change` is triggered and does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested these code snippets in codepen.io and that worked fine. No errors whatsoever.

HTML code:

```
<div id="app">
  <form>
  <input v-model="amount_ttc" @change="setAmountHtva">
  <input v-model="amount_htva" @change="setAmountTtc">
  </form>
</div>
```

JS code (you should link vuejs v2 in js settings):

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      amount_ttc: 0,
      amount_htva: 0,
      vat: 21
  },
  methods: {
    setAmountHtva () {
        this.amount_htva = parseFloat(this.amount_ttc / (1 + this.vat / 100)).toFixed(2)
    },
    setAmountTtc () {
        this.amount_ttc = parseFloat(this.amount_htva * (1 + this.vat / 100)).toFixed(2)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Hello ! Thank you ! I have already tested. Tried typing "10" in one of the two fields, you will see that it turns into 9.99

Comment: Sorry, couldn't reproduce your results. On my side: amount_ttc(10) => amount_htva(8.26) and amount_htva(10) => amount_ttc(12.10). I don't get how 10 may be turned into 9.99. Could you give me more info please.